# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception, dialog, radio-group

I've created a DialogBox `myDialog` and initialised it in `Settings.kt` activity and I am getting the above error when I am initialising the `themeRadioGroup`, although I've used a non-null assertion operator`(!!)`.
What I want to do is to change the theme of the app using radio buttons(light or dark). And those two radio buttons are in a dialog box i.e. `myDialog` and `Settings.kt` is the activity of which I want to change theme, so that's why I want to access the radio group from `myDialog`.

**Settings.kt** Activity

```
class Settings : AppCompatActivity() {
 private lateinit var themeRadioGroup : RadioGroup

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        val myDialog = Dialog(this)
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.app_info_popup)
        themeRadioGroup = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.theme_radio_group)!!
           
        //...
}
```

Comment: I don´t understand this approach... what is appInfoDialog? Probably your R.id.theme_radio_grou is not in the R.layout.activity_settings scope, so is null

Comment: I've corrected the code it's `myDialog` not `appInfoDialog`.

Comment: yes the theme_radio_group is in other xml file(dialog box) and I want to access it in `Settings` activity

Comment: Ok, i think themeRadioGroup is null because the dialog is not inflated, maybe if you show the dialog then you could find your views by id

Comment: @ManuelMato `Dialog.setContentView` immediately performs inflation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!!` is the only way you *can* get a KotlinNullPointerException. The exception means your assertion that the item is non-null is wrong. In this case, it means a view with that ID does not exist in the dialog layout you have set.

Maybe the view you are looking for is in the activity layout, in which case you should call `this.findViewById` instead of `myDialog.findViewById`.

Otherwise, check your dialog layout closely to make sure it is there. If you have multiple versions of the layout for different configurations, make sure they all have a view with that ID.

You might want to look into [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), which is designed to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: Yeah. I got it now, it was a very silly mistake I was referring the wrong layout file.